# Get HTML content from page rendered by javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, .net

Is there any solution for receive html content from page, where source code has been rendered by javascript?
I want to use this content in my C# app. 
I used WebForm, but there is no result...
I'm writting external dll (no console or windows application)

Any ideas?

Comment: you will have to load the page as an html url in an iframe and then use the dom to drill into the content you want from there.

Comment: I think you want your C# code to act as a CLIENT, take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f.aspx

Comment: @David: This solution not works...

Comment: You're looking for a headless browser.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);
```

or

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

per dan

Comment: if that's what you want, document.documentElement.outerHTML is shorter and more complete...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the html code on the client (javascript) follow @kery answer, and if you need the html code of a page on the server side (c#) maybe you can use something like that:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/204778/Get-HTML-code-from-a-website-C